# Integral inequality for a continuous and decreasing function on an interval

Tags: integration

Let $f$ be a continuous and decreasing function on $[0,1]$. Show that

$$\int_{0}^{\frac12}f(x)\,\mathrm dx \geq \frac12 \int_0^1 f(x)\,\mathrm dx$$

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages learning, you will get much more help if you show us what you have already done. Could you edit your question with your thoughts and ideas?

Answer (score 7):

HINT:

$$\int_0^1 f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^\frac{1}{2} f(x)\,\mathrm dx+\int_\frac{1}{2}^1 f(x)\,\mathrm dx$$

What can you say about those two integrals from $f$ being continuous and decreasing?

Answer (score 2):

\begin{align}
 \int_0^1 f(x)dx&=\int_0^\frac 1 2 f(x) dx +\int_\frac 1 2 ^ 1 f(x) dx\\
&\geq \int_0^\frac 1 2  f(x) dx+\int_0^\frac 1 2 f(x) dx \\
& = 2\int_0^\frac 1 2  f(x) dx
\end{align}

ie, $$ \int_0^\frac 1 2  f(x)\,\mathrm dx\leq \frac 1 2 \int_0^1 f(x)\,\mathrm dx$$
Reason is at every distinct points, with $x\leq y$, $f(x)\geq f(y)$. Now we can a take a point $x\in [0,\frac1 2] $ and $y\in [\frac 1 2 , 0]$ . clearly $f(x)\geq f(y)$ then use the integral property.

Comment: You made an error since you proved the contrary... $f$ is decreasing.

Comment: its a typo..i made the correction...

Answer (score 0):

Since $f(2y)\leq f(y)$, with a change of variable:
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{1}f(x)\,dx = \int_{0}^{1/2}f(2y)\,dy \leq \int_{0}^{1/2}f(x)\,dx.$$